# Subdomain wildcard htaccess redirection to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

One of my websites I want to redirect o another domain.

The situation:

[old] *.example.com
[new] *.example.net

for now I have this in my htaccess

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).allwebsitestats.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1.allwebsitestats.nl [R=301,L]
```

The result of this;

Request [old] *.example.com results in [new] .example.net, the problem is
it doesn't get the wildcard subdomain with it.

Thanks you!

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.allwebsitestats\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.allwebsitestats.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is almost what I need, the only problem now is that it just accept subdomains without a dot. It's possible there are subdomains with dots in like: sub.sub.example.net