# htaccess : Display homepage on wrongly typed subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I need to Display an custom url source,when users mistype an subdomain.

For example , If user types `hames.domain.com` instead of `games.domain.com` , The `hames.domain.com` should display html source of index of `domain.com`.

P.s : i dont want iframe or redirection,It needs to display index of main domain.

i tried below code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^%1/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect the htaccess to know what is a typo and what isn't?

Comment: what do u mean stephen ?

Comment: hmm, never mind, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Looks like this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028050/subdomain-wildcard-htaccess-redirection-to-new-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humm I'm not a pro with htaccess, but if the user types a wrong sub domain he'll get a 404 error. So redirect him to your domain if he gets it.

ErrorDocument 404 domain.com